# The man there was very kind and said, (about "there")

Tags: word-order

> I went to a house and asked for help. The man **there** was very kind and said, “Come in and keep warm.”

I have the mentioned sentences in the book. Is it normal to use "there" between "man" and "was"? I don't see pretty much examples on the internet (Google Books) of "The man there was very". I suppose I can say then:

> "The man **in the house** was very kind and said"...

Is it possible?

As I know it's not standard word order. Right? Why is it used? For shortness?

If it's possible to transform the second sentence into the sentence with standard word order with the same meaning, please do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usage is correct, though it is a very controversial matter about ***[adverbs modifying noun phrases](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/adjectives-adverbs/can-the-versatile-adverb-modify-a-noun/)***. In the link you will find the example

> The opportunities ***here*** are endless.

*Here* does modify *the opportunities*, but I will let you decide whether you want to call it adjective or adverb.

I will quote [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/there), with which I personally agree:

> ***there*** *adjective*
>  used for emphasis *especially after a demonstrative pronoun* or *a noun modified by a demonstrative adjective*
>
> - *Those men* ***there*** can tell you.

In you sentence it basically means, *the man [that was] there*, that is, *in that house* that was referred to in the previous sentence. By using *there*, the repetition of the word *house* was avoided.

Comment: Is it possible to say "The man **in the house** was very kind and ..." or it doesn't idiomatic?

Comment: It is idiomatic, no problem with it, except that you will repeat twice _house_ and that is usually avoided, especially in written texts. _I went to a **house** and asked for help. The man in the **house** was very kind..._